# Firebase MessagingService When app not in debug Mode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Notifications are not receiving when app is not in debug mode.
But In the firebase console it's showing as completed.

Below one is my code

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        context = (EEmployeeApplication) EEmployeeApplication.getContext();
        Log.d("Notification","From: "+remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            Log.d("FCM","Message data payload: "+remoteMessage.getData());
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("FCM", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("FCM", "Message Notification Body Verse: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("PLAN_ID"));
            String PlanID = remoteMessage.getData().get("PLAN_ID");
            context.eEMPSharedPreference.setNotification(PlanID);
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("FCM", "Message Notification Click action: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction());
        }
        String image = remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon();
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String text = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        int id = 0;
        Object obj = remoteMessage.getData().get("id");
        if (obj != null){
            id = Integer.valueOf(obj.toString());
        }
        this.sendNotification(new NotificationData(image,id,title,text));
    }

    private void sendNotification(NotificationData notificationData){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Navigationdrawer.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotificationData.TEXT,notificationData.getTextMessage());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBulder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBulder.setContentTitle(notificationData.getTitle());
        notificationBulder.setContentText(notificationData.getTextMessage());
        notificationBulder.setAutoCancel(true);
        //notificationBulder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBulder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationData.getId(), notificationBulder.build());
    }
```

How to resolve it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: if your are firing notification from console it will b directly shown in device. no need to create manual notification

Comment: @AshishPardhiye is there any issue of not receiving fcm notification by create manual notification

Comment: no issues firebase will handle on it's own

Comment: manual notification will only work if the app is in foreground. if it is in background firebase will handle it

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and you can fix this simply by overriding onCreate and put waitForDebugger method like so:

```
override fun onCreate() {
       Debug.waitForDebugger()
}
```